# Derivation of optimal portfolio weights using Risk Budgeting approach

Tags: volatility, portfolio-optimization, risk, portfolio, modern-portfolio-theory

In Thierry Roncalli's book *Introduction to Risk Parity and Budgeting* (2013), he gives an example of particular solutions to the Risk Budgeting portfolio such as for the $n=2$ asset case.

The risk contributions are:

$$
\frac{1}{\sigma(x)}
\cdot 
\begin{bmatrix}
w^2\sigma_1^2 + \rho w(1-w) \sigma_1 \sigma_2 \\
(1-w)^2\sigma_2^2 + \rho w(1-w) \sigma_1 \sigma_2 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

The vector $[b,1-b]$ are the risk budgets.

He presents the optimal weight $w$ as:

$$
w^*
=
\frac
{(b - \frac{1}{2}) \rho \sigma_1\sigma_2 - b\sigma_2^2 +\sigma_1\sigma_2\sqrt{(b - \frac{1}{2})^2\rho^2 + b(1-b)}}
{(1-b)\sigma_1^2 - b\sigma_2^2 + 2(b - \frac{1}{2})\rho\sigma_1\sigma_2}
$$

How are these weights derived ? I don't need a full derivation (it would be helpful though), I just don't know how it is derived.

Is it done by setting the risk contributions equal to the budgets?

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
b \\
1-b \\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\frac{1}{\sigma(x)}
\cdot 
\begin{bmatrix}
w^2\sigma_1^2 + \rho w(1-w) \sigma_1 \sigma_2 \\
(1-w)^2\sigma_2^2 + \rho w(1-w) \sigma_1 \sigma_2 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct in your assumption, this is specified at the start of section 2.2.1 Definition of a risk budgeting portfolio.

> We consider a set of given risk budgets $\{B_1,\dots,B_n\}$. Here
> $B_i$ is an amount of risk measured in dollars. We denote
> $\mathcal{RC}_i(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ the risk contribution of asset $i$
> with respect to portfolio $x=(x_1,\dots,x_n)$. The risk budgeting
> portfolio is then defined by the following constraints:
>
> $$ \mathcal{RC}_1(x_1,\dots,x_2)=B_1 \\ \vdots \\
>   \mathcal{RC}_i(x_1,\dots,x_2)=B_i \\ \vdots \\
>   \mathcal{RC}_n(x_1,\dots,x_2)=B_n \\ $$

**The two asset case**

We can rewrite the two equations into a singular formula by solving for $\sigma(x)$ for both of them and subsequently eliminating $\sigma(x)$ by setting the two formulations of $\sigma(x)$ equal to each other:

$$
\frac{w^2\sigma_1^2+w(1-w)\rho\sigma_1\sigma_2}{b}=
\frac{(1-w)^2\sigma_2^2+w(1-w)\rho\sigma_1\sigma_2}{1-b}
$$

After rearranging this becomes a (complicated) quadratic equation in $w$, which can be solved via [the quadratic formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula). By cancelling terms in the resulting fraction and observing that $0\leq w\leq 1$ (and thus eliminating one of the solutions of the quadratic formula) you should arrive at the optimal $w^*$.

Comment: Thank you. Is there some trick required to arrive at the final weight ? 
I get as far as solving for $w$ in one equation after rearranging as a quadratic in $w$ and substituting the result in the other, but it’s quite messy.

Comment: If you have know of a reference that contains at least a partial derivation that would be very helpful.

Comment: Edited the question, let me know if you need more details.